# Python django html tag img

Tags: python, html, django, веб-программирование, img

Фото находится в одной директории с html файлом. На сайте отображается как битая. Почему так может происходить?
base.html (путь project\taskmanager\main\templates\main\base.html)

```
...
<body>
<p>
    <img src="lagonews.png" alt="Пример">
</p>
</body>
...
```

Comment: потому что надо почитать как хранить и использовать статические файлы в django

Comment: @vadim.Sharoikin правильно я понимаю что на html языке не получится вывести? На django кстати получилось)

Comment: Попробуйте передавать в html абсолютный путь к файлу, а не относительный. То есть     <img src="C:/project/media/lagonews.png" alt="Пример">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему соблюдением структуры django приложения. img распологать следует по пути:
**my_app/static/my_app/myimage.jpg.**